# restrict filling in missing data for panda to a single index on multi-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

As an example, imagine i have a df with columns for 'year', 'quarter' (sequential through a year), a variable ('var'), and a measurement ('value'):

```
year   quarter   var  value
2015         1     A    0.1
2015         2     A    0.5
2015         3     A    0.6
2015         4     A    1.0
2015         1     B    0.1
2015         4     B    0.5
2015         2     C    0.0
2015         3     C    0.7
2015         4     C    1.2
```

but sometimes there is missing data (example: see [2015,2,'B']). it's not too much of a stretch to insert NaN's into the data using reindexing so that i get this:

```
year   quarter   var  value
2015         1     A    0.1
2015         2     A    0.5
2015         3     A    0.6
2015         4     A    1.0
2015         1     B    0.1
2015         2     B    NaN
2015         3     B    NaN
2015         4     B    0.5
2015         1     C    NaN
2015         2     C    0.0
2015         3     C    0.7
2015         4     C    1.2
```

but what i'd like to do is fill in the 'missing' data using forward-filling to propagate values - i.e. df.ffill() - and then fill in the remaining values with zero - i.e. df.fillna(0) so that you end up with something like this:

```
year   quarter   var  value
2015         1     A    0.1
2015         2     A    0.5
2015         3     A    0.6
2015         4     A    1.0
2015         1     B    0.1
2015         2     B    0.1
2015         3     B    0.1
2015         4     B    0.5
2015         1     C    0.0
2015         2     C    0.0
2015         3     C    0.7
2015         4     C    1.2
```

however, when i use df.ffill(), i haven't found a way to restrict/partition by 'var' or 'year'.

my first idea was to convert the data to a pivot table:

```
pd.pivot_table(data,values='value',index=['year','quarter'],columns='var',aggfunc=np.sum)
```

and then do the forward-fill but i cannot figure how to restrict to year (or how to unpack the pivot table back to it's original form).

any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: sorry are you asking for `df.loc[(df['year'] == 2015) & (df['var') == 'B'), 'var'].fillna(method='ffill')` and then for the other one `df.loc[(df['year'] == 2015) & (df['var') == 'C'), 'var'].fillna(0)`?

Comment: that's the idea. but the truth is that the actual data is far too large to reasonably do it that way. cycling through all of the values ends up taking several minutes for an operation that will need to be run quite often.

Comment: though if i edit the pivot table create statement to change `year` to the columns from the index, i _seem_ to get what i'm looking for but i'm having a great bit of difficulty in unpacking the new table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically need your data in a table with time along your row indices and everything else in columns.  You can use a pivot table or stack/unstack:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['year', 'quarter', 'var']).unstack('var')
>>> df2
             value          
var              A    B    C
year quarter                
2015 1         0.1  0.1  NaN
     2         0.5  NaN  0.0
     3         0.6  NaN  0.7
     4         1.0  0.5  1.2
```

Once the data is in this form, then forward fill and back fill.

```
df2 = df2.ffill().bfill(0)
```

Finally, stack and sort your data, and then reset your index if desired:

```
   >>> df2.stack('var').sortlevel(2).reset_index()
        year  quarter var  value
    0   2015        1   A    0.1
    1   2015        2   A    0.5
    2   2015        3   A    0.6
    3   2015        4   A    1.0
    4   2015        1   B    0.1
    5   2015        2   B    0.1
    6   2015        3   B    0.1
    7   2015        4   B    0.5
    8   2015        1   C    0.0
    9   2015        2   C    0.0
    10  2015        3   C    0.7
    11  2015        4   C    1.2
```

Comment: thanks! the major issue i was having was not using `.reset_index()` for after stacking the pivot_table.